# Ensure only a single instance of static template class member

Tags: c++, thread-safety, template, singleton, static

I am interacting with a C library, whose documentation states that certain functions are not thread safe. Since its functions deal heterogeneously with multiple types, I have written a template wrapper to use it in a homogeneous manner from C++. However, I now need to ensure serialized access to certain functions, serialized across all instantiated template wrappers.

I believe the following approach *should* work; what I would like to know is, ***are there any caveats to the following approach, and if so, what are they and how can I get around them?***

```
struct LibMutexPolicy
{
    static std::mutex & getMutexInstance()
    {
        static std::mutex inst;
        return inst;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct A : private LibMutexPolicy
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(getMutexInstance());
        // Call non thread-safe library code
    }
};
```

Comment: I would do that. If you use it in a destructor then you need to be careful (just put a call in the constructor to compensate). The reason is if a user of your code creates a static storage duration object (global) then there could be some lifetime issues.

Comment: This will work (keep in mind Loki's comment). Another issue (not sure if this is a problem for your application) is that you will add shared state between the objects, in a non-obvious way. This could be made obvious, by using dependency injection for your mutex. Have you considered it?

Comment: @utnapistim I haven't really considered it; the wrapper is around FFTW, and I've tried quite hard to keep the constructor interface as simple as possible because there are quite a few facets to its functionality. My feeling is that dependency injection would complicate the interface **unless** it could be done via a true policy-based design (e.g., perhaps the policy has lock() and unlock() and then I use std::lock_guard<LibLockingPolicy>). Any thoughts? Would this make for a better design?

Comment: @wakjah, I have added an example in response, using an external (non-intrusive) decorator for synchronization. It is the most flexible I can think of, but it imposes lambdas in client code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe the following approach should work; what I would like to know is, are there any caveats to the following approach, and if so, what are they and how can I get around them?

Consider a decorator implementation, with a visitor function for method access:

```
template<typename V>
class threadsafe_reference // decorator
{
public:
    using reference_type = V&;
    threadsafe_reference(reference_type v, std::mutex& m): value_(v), mutex_(m) {}

    // synchronized visitor access
    void sync( std::function<void(value_type&)> functor )
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mutex_ };
        functor( value_ );
    }

    // you may wish to provide unsynchronized reference access here
private:
    reference_type value_;
    std::mutex& mutex_; 
};

template<typename V>
threadsafe_reference<V> make_threadsafe(V& value, std::mutex& m)
{
    return threadsafe_reference<V>{ value, m };
}
```

Client code:

```
struct A // agnostic to threading
{
    void do_stuff_n_things( int i ) {};
};

A a; // need to pass this on two threads
mutex m;

auto tsa = make_threadsafe(a, m); // proxy accessor
```

Thread access:

```
 tsa.sync( []( A& self ) { self.do_things_n_stuff(10); } );
```

The code is incomplete (you'd need a specialization of sync for const access and so on) but it should be enough to give you a picture.

Advantages:

- this is a non-intrusive decorator that you can use over virtually any type
- separates concerns nicely and allows you to implement and test them separately (e.g. test A, then test the synchronization code)

Minor disadvantage:

- the access to A's methods requires lambdas/external functions